# Using continuity to prove f is a constant function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Recently missed this problem on an exam. Just went to office hours to clarify what the proper proof was and wanted to see if, in attempting to repeat the problem, I can figure out if there are better ways to do it / if I remember how to even do it properly. Also, for reference, I'm using Kenneth A. Ross's *Elementary Analysis: The Theory of Calculus*, second edition. Indeed, I use his Intermediate Value Theorem and Density of Rationals within my proof.

> *Let $f$ be a continuous function such that for $f : (m,M) \to \mathbb R$, $f(x)$ is an irrational number whenever $x \in (m ,M)$. Prove $f$ is a constant function. Note: m and M are integers.*
>
> > **Proof:**
> >
> > I will proceed by contradiction. Assume $f$ is not constant, yet still satisfies the premise.
> >
> > Let $x,y \in (m , M)$, $x < y$,  and $f(x)<f(y)$.
> >
> > By the premise given above, $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are irrational numbers. However, by the Intermediate Value Theorem, $\exists$ $x < a < y$ such that $f(x) < f(a) < f(y)$.
> >
> > Additionally, by the density of the rationals, $\exists$ an $a \in (x , y)$ such that $f(a)$ is a rational number. This contradicts our premise by which $\forall x \in (m , M)$ is an irrational number.
> >
> > Therefore, we can conclude that our given function $f$ is constant.

I'm still a little uneasy about this proof--I have a nagging feeling that an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition should be involved...

Comment: It looks good to me (you are missing something like '$f(x)$ is an irrational number').

Comment: Another proof is that since $f$ is continuous, it maps connected sets into connected sets. Since the connected sets in $\mathbb{R}$ are the intervals, this means that $f$ must be constant. Essentially the same as you have.

Comment: You're missing a small detail regarding the possibility that $f$ is strictly decreasing, i.e. that there are _no_ $x< y$ such that $f(x)<f(y)$. But if $f(x)>f(y)$, then the same argument still holds, and otherwise it looks good.

Answer (score 3):

I would mention the density of the rationals **before** invoking the Intermediate Value Theorem (as it's not explicitly clear how your two different versions of $a$ are related). Otherwise, your proof has the right idea. Here's my version:

---

Suppose instead that $f$ is not constant. Then without loss of generality, we know that there exist $x,y \in (m, M)$ such that $x < y$ and $f(x) < f(y)$. Now by the density of the rationals, we know that there is some rational $r \in (f(x), f(y))$. Thus, since $f$ is continuous, it follows by the Intermediate Value Theorem that there is some $c \in (x,y)$ such that $f(c) = r \in \mathbb Q$. But this contradicts our premise that $f(k)$ is irrational for all $k \in (m,M)$. So $f$ must indeed be constant, as desired. $~~\blacksquare$